Multiple Rails routing errors for JavaScript files while importmap
I started a new project. It uses phlex-rails, phlex_ui and tailwindcss-rails, plus the plethora of usual stuff Rails provides by default. This time around, I wanted to learn more about Rails 7 and importmap.
Whenever I get a page, the page loads for a few seconds, then displays correctly. When looking at the logs, I see many GET requests for many files:
Started GET "/assets/sub/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/assets/subBusinessDays/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/assets/subDays/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/assets/subHours/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/assets/subISOWeekYears/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/assets/subMilliseconds/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/assets/subMinutes/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/assets/subMonths/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400

I'm guessing these are normal because the asset pipeline isn't present. I would have expected these files to be cached, but it doesn't really matter.
What does matter are these ones instead:
Started GET "/assets/weeksToDays/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/assets/yearsToMonths/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/assets/yearsToQuarters/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/_/a28ffa54.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/_/d2e90c22.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/assets/_lib/toInteger/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/assets/_lib/getTimezoneOffsetInMilliseconds/index.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/_/bdf2ba0c.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/_/a28ffa54.js"):


ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/_/d2e90c22.js"):

Started GET "/_/43b08ee2.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/_/bdf2ba0c.js"):

Started GET "/_/18a96f2b.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/_/35814e45.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400
Started GET "/_/9f5bb25a.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-04-16 09:46:08 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/_/43b08ee2.js"):


ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/_/18a96f2b.js"):

Notice the routing errors: No route matches [GET] "/_/18a96f2b.js".
I'm wondering what these errors are about.
I have difficulty searching the web for these errors, since the paths seem to be some kind of hash? Any pointers appreciated!

I'm not ruby expert, but aren't those your compiled files ?

@MGX, I tracked down that many of those requests are coming from date-fns, which is a dependency of phlex_ui. I ended up grepping my working copy and found a reference to 18a96f2b in date-fns. Seems like that's an error in date-fns then.

importmap-rails v2 is currently broken, because of one change to always download files instead of using cdn:
https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/pull/217
Downgrading to v1 seems like the easiest path currently:
# Gemfile 

gem "importmap-rails", "~> 1.2"

Then pin your packages again bin/importmap pin.


...But you're also free to just manually point to a CDN. Or use 1.2.x.
https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/issues/230#issuecomment-1906207824

